# C# change ListViewGroup header text to bold

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, fonts

I have `ListView` control with `ListViewGroup` headers set. I wanted to set the group header's text to bold. Are there any alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: The lvGroupHeader is not well supported, unfortunately.unfortunately..

Comment: @TaW I have tagged "winforms". I'm sorry if you cannot see that.

Comment: Now I can see it, strange..

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.listview.group(v=vs.110).aspx) has a rather involved example. Not for the faint of heart..

Comment: @pradeeppradyumna Did you managed to solve this ?

Comment: @Ayorus no, not yet.

Answer (score -1):

### Create a temp font from the item using bold

##

```
  using(Font f= new Font(listView1.Items(0).SubItems(0).Font, FontSytle.Bold))
```

{

}

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below xaml

```
<ListView Name="lvUsers">
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
 </ListView>
```

Comment: I can use this in WPF. But I'm using Winforms :)